# Node and variables for different environments

Tags: node.js

For my Node app, what's generally seen as the way to define variables for a development and production environment. For example I want to use my local db and remote db for the two environments respectively.

For example, I'm doing this at the moment but I know it can be improved:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env)
  var db = 'mongodb://localhost/dbname'
else
  var db = 'path_to_remote_db'
```

I thought that dotenv would be the solution because it mentions setting environment variables but I think environment variables and variables for environments are two different things?

Could someone show me how I make use of variables for two different environments.

Comment: how does process.env.NODE_ENV get set?

Answer (score 0):

There are [dozens of modules](https://www.npmjs.org/browse/keyword/config) on npm for this and it is a topic rife with opinions and bike shedding. I wrote a module called [config3](https://www.npmjs.org/package/config3) that implements my personal view on a good way to handle this, and in the README I review a dozen or so other available options.

Comment: So how would I use your module for my issue then? Your example code is just one line. How do I divide into environments?

Comment: Read the section labeled  "How to Use It" in the README. That is a step-by-step guide. My approach doesn't use NODE_ENV or name the environments, you just create a configuration file at `/etc/myapp/config.js` and in staging you put the staging settings there, on your prod server, you put the production settings there. That's it.

Comment: so I can have two different config files in two locations right? It will detect the current environment and load the right one?